# What does '-P' mean in the context of the 'ps' command?

Tags: linux, ps, options

If is executed `ps -p 3384 3395` (observe `-p` is lowercase) then the output is as follows:

```
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 3384 tty6     S+     0:00 man ls
 3395 tty6     S+     0:00 pager
```

Until here all fine and is expected.

Just by mistake was executed `ps -P 3384 3395` (observe `-P` is **uppercase**) then the output is as follows:

```
 PID PSR TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 3384   2 tty6     S+     0:00 man ls
 3395   3 tty6     S+     0:00 pager
```

Observe in this output appears a new header - it is `PSR`

**Question**

- What does `-P` mean in the context of the `ps` command?

And yes, I already read both `man ps` and `ps --help all` where appears the documentation for the `-p` option/parameter as follows respectively:

```
  # Approach 1
   p pidlist
     Select by process ID. Identical to -p and --pid.

  -p pidlist
     Select by PID. This selects the processes whose process ID numbers appear in pidlist.  
     Identical to p and --pid.

  # Approach 2
  -p, p, --pid <PID> process id
        --ppid <PID> parent process id
```

But about `-P` does not appear nothing. To be honest when the `ps` command was executed with `-P` - theoretically I expected an error because `-P` does not exist, it because `-P` is not documented.

**Extra Questions**

- If `-P` theoretically does not exist because is not documented, Why an error was not thrown?
- What does `PSR` mean?

Comment: help.c has a comment that suggests someone knows that `-P` is missing. https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/newlib/ps/help.c#L214

Comment: Per https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/newlib/ps/parser.c#L300:
"-P adds columns of PRM info (HP-UX), PSR (SunOS), or capabilities (IRIX)\n"

Comment: @BowlOfRed huge thanks!, consider to add your answer to mark it how valid. About `PSR (SunOS)`, interesting, because in my case is in `Ubuntu`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any knowledge of why `-P` is not documented.  I wonder if the feature was not fully supported at some point in the past?

`-P` (or `-o psr`) sets the output to include `PSR`, which the manual states is:

```
       psr         PSR       processor that process is currently assigned to.
```

There is a [comment](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/newlib/ps/help.c#L214) in the help code for ps that suggests `-P` is "missing" from the help.  Going back to the initial checkin that I can find, several other flags used to be so marked (including `-c`, `-L`, and `-M`).  This is the only of the "dash" options I see still listed as missing from the help page.

Answer (score 2):

It indicates which processor is currently being used to execute the process. Even though the `-P` option is not documented, `PSR` is described under `STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS` in the manpage for `ps`.