# ps command: strange behavior with 'O' option, extra column/header does not appear as expected

Tags: ps, options

About the `ps` command - to add one/many extra column/header with the default headers according with the option(s) used with the `ps` command - it through `O` the option.

**Intro**

If `ps x` is executed the output is as follows:

```
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 1677 ?        Ss     0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
 1679 ?        S      0:00 (sd-pam)
 1704 tty1     S+     0:00 -bash
 1961 tty4     S      0:00 -bash
 1973 tty4     S+     0:00 man ps
 1983 tty4     S+     0:00 pager
 2227 ?        S      0:00 sshd: manueljordan@pts/0
 2228 pts/0    Ss     0:00 -bash
 2307 ?        S      0:01 sshd: manueljordan@pts/1
 2308 pts/1    Ss     0:00 -bash
 2407 ?        S      0:00 sshd: manueljordan@pts/2
 2408 pts/2    Ss     0:00 -bash
 2437 pts/2    S+     0:00 less
 2846 pts/1    S+     0:00 man ps
 2856 pts/1    S+     0:00 pager
 2968 pts/0    R+     0:00 ps x
```

Appears and we know the default set of column/headers.

How a simple confirmation - if `ps xO %cpu` is executed the output is as follows:

```
  PID %CPU S TTY          TIME COMMAND
 1677  0.0 S ?        00:00:00 systemd
 1679  0.0 S ?        00:00:00 (sd-pam)
 1704  0.0 S tty1     00:00:00 bash
 1961  0.0 S tty4     00:00:00 bash
 1973  0.0 S tty4     00:00:00 man
 1983  0.0 S tty4     00:00:00 pager
 2227  0.0 S ?        00:00:00 sshd
 2228  0.0 S pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 2307  0.0 S ?        00:00:01 sshd
 2308  0.0 S pts/1    00:00:00 bash
 2407  0.0 S ?        00:00:00 sshd
 2408  0.0 S pts/2    00:00:00 bash
 2437  0.0 S pts/2    00:00:00 less
 2846  0.0 S pts/1    00:00:00 man
 2856  0.0 S pts/1    00:00:00 pager
 2969  0.0 R pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

Until here all is ok. No reason to create this post

Therefore theoretically can be added any `HEADER` based on with its respective `CODE` - it according with the `STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS` section, it available through `man ps`.

Now thanks with the experience of this question:

- [What does '-P' mean in the context of the 'ps' command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/701422/what-does-p-mean-in-the-context-of-the-ps-command)

Appears the `PSR` column/header.

**Situation**

If `ps xO psr` is executed the output is as follows:

```
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 1677 ?        Ss     0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
 1679 ?        S      0:00 (sd-pam)
 1704 tty1     S+     0:00 -bash
 1961 tty4     S      0:00 -bash
 1973 tty4     S+     0:00 man ps
 1983 tty4     S+     0:00 pager
 2227 ?        S      0:00 sshd: manueljordan@pts/0
 2228 pts/0    Ss     0:00 -bash
 2307 ?        S      0:01 sshd: manueljordan@pts/1
 2308 pts/1    Ss     0:00 -bash
 2407 ?        S      0:00 sshd: manueljordan@pts/2
 2408 pts/2    Ss     0:00 -bash
 2437 pts/2    S+     0:00 less
 2846 pts/1    S+     0:00 man ps
 2856 pts/1    S+     0:00 pager
 2975 pts/0    R+     0:00 ps xO psr
```

If you realize the `PSR` does **not** appear, why?

But if `ps xO %cpu,psr` is executed the output is:

```
  PID %CPU PSR S TTY          TIME COMMAND
 1677  0.0   1 S ?        00:00:00 systemd
 1679  0.0   2 S ?        00:00:00 (sd-pam)
 1704  0.0   1 S tty1     00:00:00 bash
 1961  0.0   0 S tty4     00:00:00 bash
 1973  0.0   1 S tty4     00:00:00 man
 1983  0.0   2 S tty4     00:00:00 pager
 2227  0.0   3 S ?        00:00:00 sshd
 2228  0.0   3 S pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 2307  0.0   3 S ?        00:00:01 sshd
 2308  0.0   3 S pts/1    00:00:00 bash
 2407  0.0   0 S ?        00:00:00 sshd
 2408  0.0   0 S pts/2    00:00:00 bash
 2437  0.0   0 S pts/2    00:00:00 less
 2846  0.0   0 S pts/1    00:00:00 man
 2856  0.0   0 S pts/1    00:00:00 pager
 2981  0.0   0 R pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

or if `ps xO uname,psr` is executed the output is:

```
  PID USER     PSR S TTY          TIME COMMAND
 1677 manuelj+   1 S ?        00:00:00 systemd
 1679 manuelj+   2 S ?        00:00:00 (sd-pam)
 1704 manuelj+   1 S tty1     00:00:00 bash
 1961 manuelj+   0 S tty4     00:00:00 bash
 1973 manuelj+   1 S tty4     00:00:00 man
 1983 manuelj+   2 S tty4     00:00:00 pager
 2227 manuelj+   3 S ?        00:00:00 sshd
 2228 manuelj+   3 S pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 2307 manuelj+   3 S ?        00:00:01 sshd
 2308 manuelj+   3 S pts/1    00:00:00 bash
 2407 manuelj+   0 S ?        00:00:00 sshd
 2408 manuelj+   0 S pts/2    00:00:00 bash
 2437 manuelj+   0 S pts/2    00:00:00 less
 2846 manuelj+   0 S pts/1    00:00:00 man
 2856 manuelj+   0 S pts/1    00:00:00 pager
 2982 manuelj+   0 R pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

How you can see when is declared at least another extra header to be added together with the `PSR` header, just then/only `PSR` appears in the output.

Why the `PSR` header does not appear when is declared how the unique extra header to be added through the `O` option? Is it an expected behavior for some reason?

Comment: Well, the man page for the `procps-ng 3.3.16` implementation says of `O` that it is *"(overloaded)"* and that *"Heuristics are used to determine the behavior of this option."* - my *guess* is that the heuristic in this case identifies `Opsr` as a sort option with a set of `OBSOLETE SORT KEYS`, rather than as a "user-defined output format with some common fields predefined".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend not using the `O` option like that because it can lead to confusion because it behavior changes depending on what fields it gets and quite often it is very confusing.

So you probably see `ps xO psr` and think that means it should sort and show the `PSR` (last processor used) column?

It's not doing that actually.

@steeldriver above nailed it, it's sorting with the old keys. So you are asking `ps` to sort by: pid "p", size "s" and RSS "r". Sorting by `rsp` or `spr` are just as valid, with different order of sorting of course.

Why does `ps xO psr,%cpu` or even for that matter `ps xO psr,psr` change things? ps now realises you don't want the old sort keys and are using the name of columns to sort.

Comment: I didn't know about the old keys, and I expected the same behavior with 1 or 2 columns. So due this strange behavior with just 1 column and by coincidence for the `PSR` column I created this post